# create an array of dates in bash scripts and match it current date

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

Actually I want to create an array of dates and compare it to the today date if it match with the current date then execute `test.sh` file otherwise exit the loop in bash script. I did like this...

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/user1

current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

array=['2016-03-02','2016-03-010','2016-05-10']

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
if [ $now -eq $i ]; then
        echo "executing your bash script file"
    ./myscript.sh
fi
done
```

when i execute above script then it gives error like

```
./sample.sh: line 6: [: 2016-03-02: integer expression expected
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it this way:

```
current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

array=('2016-03-02' '2016-03-010' '2016-05-10')

for i in "${array[@]}" ; do

    if [ "$current_date" == "$i" ]
        then echo "executing your bash script file"
        #./myscript.sh
    fi

done
```

The mistakes:

1. don't use square brackets to declare an array in a bash script - these brackets make commands (see 'if'-tests)
2. array-elements in bash scripts are separated by whitespaces (no commas)
3. if you want to compare strings, use double-quotes around the variables, which hold these strings
4. do not use '-eq' as operator here (because it's an arithmetic-operator). Instead use '==' or '!=' (see here too: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-11.html)

Comment: yes its done! thank you so much for your kind effort.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pull `bash` or arrays for that. You can do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
if grep -qx "$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" << EOF
2016-03-02
2016-03-01
2016-05-10
EOF
then
   test.sh
fi
```

or:

```
#! /bin/sh -
dates="2016-03-02 2016-03-01 2016-05-10"
case " $dates " in
  *" $(date +%Y-%m-%d) "*)
     test.sh
esac
```

Or just:

```
#! /bin/sh -
case $(date +%Y-%m-%d) in
  2016-03-02|2016-03-01|2016-05-10) test.sh
esac
```

For searchable arrays, I'd rather use `zsh` than `bash`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

dates=(2016-03-02 2016-03-01 2016-05-10)
if ((dates[(I)$(date +%Y-%m-%d)])) test.sh
```